# Simple algebra square root inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

For $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{c^2+d^2} \geq \sqrt{(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2}$? I have tried to show this using the fact that $\sqrt{x+y}\leq\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\; $  for non-negative $x,y$ but haven't been able to arrive at a proof.

Comment: Hm, the most immediate first step would be to square both sides.

Comment: Yes, that gives $\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)} \geq? ac + bd$ but where to proceed from there?

Comment: try some examples is the next step. Many examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the vectors $x=\langle{a,b}\rangle$ and $y=\langle{c,d}\rangle$
By the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), we have that $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{c^2+d^2}=||x||+||y|| \ge ||x+y|| =\sqrt{(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2}$$
So we have $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{c^2+d^2} \ge \sqrt{(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Squaring both sides gives $\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}\geq ac+bd$ you already have. Another squaring gives $a^2d^2+b^2c^2\geq 2abcd$, which has $x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$ structure, which holds.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vectors $v_1=\langle{a,b}\rangle$ and $v_2=\langle{c,d}\rangle$. Recall that the dot product can be written as 
$$v_1 \cdot v_2 = |v_1||v_2|\cos\theta\leq|v_1||v_2|.$$
Then we substitute:
$$v_1 \cdot v_2 = ac+bd\leq|v_1||v_2|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}.$$
This proves the simplification you made, and therefore proves that 
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{c^2+d^2} \geq \sqrt{(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2}. \quad\quad\square$$